# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote this SQL query

```
select 
    acc.DepartmentID,
    dept.DepartmentName,
    dept.DepartmentDivision,
    county.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvinceID
from [AccountDepartmentXREF] acc
inner join [Department] dept on dept.DepartmentID = acc.DepartmentID
left join [DepartmentStateCountyXREF] dscx on dscx.DepartmentID = acc.DepartmentID
left join [StateCounty] county on county.StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID
inner join [StateProvince] sp on sp.StateProvinceID = dept.StateProvinceID
where acc.AccountID = 1
```

and want to rewrite it using LINQ, but I always get confused when writing left joins in LINQ, so I decided to use a convertor and went with Linqer and this is what it produced

```
from acc in db.AccountDepartmentXREF
join dscx in db.DepartmentStateCountyXREF on acc.DepartmentID equals dscx.DepartmentID into dscx_join
from dscx in dscx_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join county in db.StateCounty on new { StateCountyID = Convert.ToInt32(dscx.StateCountyID) } equals new { StateCountyID = county.StateCountyID } into county_join
from county in county_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join sp in db.StateProvince on acc.Department.StateProvinceID equals sp.StateProvinceID
where
acc.AccountID == 1
select new {
acc.DepartmentID,
acc.Department.DepartmentName,
acc.Department.DepartmentDivision,
CountyName = county.CountyName,
sp.StateProvinceID
}
```

so when I put everything together in code

```
public List<DepartmentList> GetDepartmentsByAccountID(string email)
    {
        HWC = new HWCEntities();
        List<DepartmentList> result = new List<DepartmentList>();

        int id = CurrentUserID(email);

        List<AccountDepartmentXREF> adx = HWC.AccountDepartmentXREFs.Where(w => w.AccountID == id).ToList();

        foreach(var a in adx)
        {
            var query = from acc in HWC.AccountDepartmentXREFs
                        join dscx in HWC.DepartmentStateCountyXREFs on acc.DepartmentID equals dscx.DepartmentID into dscx_join
                        from dscx in dscx_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                                
                        join county in HWC.StateCounties on new { StateCountyID = Convert.ToInt32(dscx.StateCountyID) } equals new { StateCountyID = county.StateCountyID } into county_join
                        from county in county_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join sp in HWC.StateProvinces on acc.Department.StateProvinceID equals sp.StateProvinceID
                        where
                          acc.AccountID == a.AccountID
                        select new
                        {
                            acc.DepartmentID,
                            acc.Department.DepartmentName,
                            acc.Department.DepartmentDivision,
                            CountyName = county.CountyName,
                            sp.StateProvinceID
                        };

            foreach(var b in query)
            {
                result.Add(new DepartmentList
                {
                    DepartmentID = b.DepartmentID,
                    DepartmentName = b.DepartmentName,
                    StateProvinceID = b.StateProvinceID,
                    DivisionName = b.DepartmentDivision,
                    CountyName = b.CountyName
                });
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I get the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

at the

> foreach(var b in query)

Any idea's on how to fix this? I have looked around but other solutions I found aren't dealing with joins

Comment: Google your error. The first page is full of solutions.

Comment: @FCin, yea, already did that. I got it figured out though, I had a column that allowed nulls in one of the tables. None of those solutions on the first page had identified that that could have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Linq doesn't support the Convert.ToInt32(dscx.StateCountyID) method inside the query because this will need to be converted to sql for execution on the db.

I am not sure what datatype StateCountyID is in both tables but you will need to use some sql compatible conversion method like SqlFunctions.StringConvert() to get them to the same datatype.

Comment: If I remove that then I get an error on that join about The Type of one of the expressions in the join clause is in incorrect, and then in the foreach I get an error cannot operate on variables of type '?'

Comment: they are both ints

Comment: Then you shouldn't need any conversion.  The fact that you are getting type conversion errors would indicate they aren't the same type.  One way around that is to use the StringConvert in SqlFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to Strings

```
from acc in HWC.AccountDepartmentXREFs
                        join dscx in HWC.DepartmentStateCountyXREFs on acc.DepartmentID equals dscx.DepartmentID into dscx_join
                        from dscx in dscx_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                                
                        join county in HWC.StateCounties on new { StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID.ToString() } equals new { StateCountyID = county.StateCountyID.ToString() }
```

or use the below:

```
dscx.StateCountyID equals SqlFunctions.Convert(county.StateCountyID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I was getting that error. It was because I had StateCountyID as nullable in my DepartmentStateCountyXREF table. Once I changed the StateCountyID column from a nullable and then removed the Convert.ToInt32, everything worked.